# GTK+3 application won't run on Windows

Tags: cmd, gtk, gtk3, mingw32, msys2

When I try the `example-0.c` on https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html, I can build successfully in my `cmd` (I have configured the PATH environment variable), but run with the errors as the snapshot below.

[image]
[image]

Also note if I didn't close the first error msgbox quickly, the second error msgbox won't shown. This is really strange.

However, I can run it (`./example-0.exe`) without this problem in my `C:\msys32\mingw32.exe`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `zlib1.dll` problem. See [github issue](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/3794#issuecomment-392062246) for more details.